# “Friendly fire” for enemies in the Dark Souls series

Tags: dark-souls-series

In *Dark Souls* enemies can hit through other enemies without damaging them.

Is this also true for:

- Dark Souls 2
- Dark Souls 3

Comment: You are asking about six different games in one question. Don't do that.

Comment: @pppery they’re very related though. Same developer and same genre.

Comment: @viuser the fact that the games are from the same developer and same genre is irrelevant. Each game is completely different, and the answer may vary between them. It’s like asking where you can find a Weedle in Pokemon Let’s Go and Pokemon Sword; one has one, the other doesn’t

Comment: @Wondercricket why is it wrong to ask about different games in the same question in the first place?

Comment: @viuser Because the question you're asking is about a mechanic that exists in video games, and just because it's under one developer, doesn't mean that it's specific. For example you could also include which of the Legend of Zelda games don't have friendly fire in the same question; and if we follow that rule, this could get out of hand *very* quickly.

Comment: You could limit it to the [tag:dark-souls-series], but Demon's Souls and Sekiro are different games; same as Bloodborne. There's nothing wrong with asking multiple questions to cover multiple titles/series.

Answer (score 2):

Your original premise is already wrong.

[Bounding Demon of Izalith](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/bounding-demon-of-izalith) from Dark Souls can hurt each other.

Subsequently, there are other enemies like so in the other games.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your "question" is more of a statement. Might want to review that.

Secondly, to address the reason for this; it is so you cannot simply farm enemies by funneling them into a small areas and simply letting them kill each other. this would make the game(s) too easy. For enemies that can damage/kill each other (as mentioned in [Nelson's Answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/392409/73976)), this is in an area that makes doing this difficult at best, but also allows it so that it's not impossible to face off against more than one at a time.

This series sold itself quite successfully with the tag line "You Will Die". The reception of the game would be very different if people found that this challenge is so easily overcome by simply funneling enemies into a tight corridor and holding up a shield.